# after connect to remote database script doesn't exit

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ssh-tunnel

I connect to remote database. I'm using sshtunnel for this. I have no problem to connect to DB and get access to data.

My problem is that, my script doesn't exit after everything.
I create connection, download data, print data, stop ssh connection, print 'exit'. This script has cease working at line server.stop() and doesn't print 'stop'. I need to interrupt it to stop working this code.

This is code:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('host', 22),
    ssh_password='password',
    ssh_username='username',
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
)
server.start()

engine = create_engine(
    'mysql+mysqldb://db_user:db_pass@127.0.0.1:{}/temps'.format(server.local_bind_port))

query = 'SELECT * FROM temp'

df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)
print(df.head())
print(df.tail())

server.stop()
print('stop')
```

This script doesn't print 'stop'.

Question: Why this code can not stop working?

## EDIT:

I added

> trace_logger = create_logger(loglevel="TRACE")

After this I notice something interesting. Code with data transfer hasn't contain one line: Transport is closed. I checked my code without sending sql query and script has correctly finished.

### logs with data transfer

```
2018-10-07 18:41:43,274| WAR | MainThrea/0967@sshtunnel | Could not read SSH configuration file: ~/.ssh/config
2018-10-07 18:41:43,275| INF | MainThrea/0993@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from agent
2018-10-07 18:41:43,275| INF | MainThrea/1042@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from host directory
2018-10-07 18:41:43,275| INF | MainThrea/0914@sshtunnel | Connecting to gateway: 192.168.0.102:22 as user ‘xxx’
2018-10-07 18:41:43,275| DEB | MainThrea/0917@sshtunnel | Concurrent connections allowed: True
2018-10-07 18:41:43,275| DEB | MainThrea/1369@sshtunnel | Trying to log in with password: xxx
2018-10-07 18:41:43,600| INF | Srv-56620/1389@sshtunnel | Opening tunnel: 0.0.0.0:56620 <> 127.0.0.1:3306
….. # data transfer
2018-10-07 18:41:43,945| INF | MainThrea/1328@sshtunnel | Closing all open connections...
<Logger sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder (TRACE)>
2018-10-07 18:41:43,945| DEB | MainThrea/1332@sshtunnel | Listening tunnels: 0.0.0.0:56620
2018-10-07 18:41:43,945| INF | MainThrea/1408@sshtunnel | Shutting down tunnel ('0.0.0.0', 56620)
2018-10-07 18:41:44,048| INF | Srv-56620/1395@sshtunnel | Tunnel: 0.0.0.0:56620 <> 127.0.0.1:3306 released
```

### logs without data transfer

```
2018-10-07 18:37:54,016| WAR | MainThrea/0967@sshtunnel | Could not read SSH configuration file: ~/.ssh/config
2018-10-07 18:37:54,017| INF | MainThrea/0993@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from agent
2018-10-07 18:37:54,017| INF | MainThrea/1042@sshtunnel | 0 keys loaded from host directory
2018-10-07 18:37:54,017| INF | MainThrea/0914@sshtunnel | Connecting to gateway: 192.168.0.102:22 as user ‘xxx'
2018-10-07 18:37:54,017| DEB | MainThrea/0917@sshtunnel | Concurrent connections allowed: True
2018-10-07 18:37:54,017| DEB | MainThrea/1369@sshtunnel | Trying to log in with password: xxx
2018-10-07 18:37:54,342| INF | Srv-56560/1389@sshtunnel | Opening tunnel: 0.0.0.0:56560 <> 127.0.0.1:3306
2018-10-07 18:37:54,363| INF | MainThrea/1328@sshtunnel | Closing all open connections...
<Logger sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder (TRACE)>
2018-10-07 18:37:54,363| DEB | MainThrea/1332@sshtunnel | Listening tunnels: 0.0.0.0:56560
2018-10-07 18:37:54,363| INF | MainThrea/1408@sshtunnel | Shutting down tunnel ('0.0.0.0', 56560)
2018-10-07 18:37:54,448| INF | Srv-56560/1395@sshtunnel | Tunnel: 0.0.0.0:56560 <> 127.0.0.1:3306 released
2018-10-07 18:37:54,448| DEB | MainThrea/1422@sshtunnel | Transport is closed
```

Comment: What is your sshtunnel version? Have you tried add a line `server.tunnel_is_up = {('127.0.0.1', 3306):False}` before `server.start()`?

Comment: sshtunnel version 0.1.4. Yes I tried with tunnel_is_up but result was the same.

Comment: Could you pass logger with `TRACE` loglevel to `SSHTunnelForwarder`? You can create it with `trace_logger = sshtunnel.create_logger(loglevel="TRACE")` Maybe this will provide more information on what is happening under the hood.

Comment: @KamilNiski I added logs

Comment: @Cezary.Sz I'm starting to suspect that there are not closed sqlalchemy connections. Could you try using `engine.dispose()` after calling `df = pd.read_sql(query, engine)`?

Comment: @KamilNiski correct, after adding engine.dispose() everything works fine!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After log inspection it turns out that `sqlalchemy` open connections was the problem.

We created `trace_logger = sshtunnel.create_logger(loglevel="TRACE")` and passed it to `SSHTunnelForwarder`

To anyone for future reference:

Adding `engine.dispose()` after `df.read_sql` will close all hanging connections to database allowing the ssh tunnel to be closed.

[Relevant documentation from sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#engine-disposal)

Answer (score 3):

Just want to add to this in case anyone has the same issue where `engine.dispose()` doesn't work. I'm on windows python 3.7. Took me hours to find the solution

issuing `server.daemon_forward_servers = True` before `server.start()` fixed the problem for me.

More references here:
https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/issues/138